# nginx: rewrite regex to match URL without digit at the end

Tags: regex, nginx, regex-lookarounds, nginx-location

I'm trying to set up a rewrite rule to accomplish the following:

- `/base/{first}` -> `/base/search/{first}`
- `/base/{first}/{second}` -> `/base/search/{first}/{second}`

And of course `/base/search/{first}` shouldn't redirect to `/base/search/search/{first}`

`{first}` and `{second}` are placeholders for strings with alphabetical characters and dashes (no digits).

However, I don't want to rewrite URLs like the following:

- `/base/{first}/{second}/{third}/{123}`

`{123}` is a placeholder for a three-character digits-only string

I've tried the following location block and I can get the first two requirements, but it's also capturing URLs that end in `{123}`

```
location ~* ^/base/(?!search)[^\d]+$ {
  rewrite ^/base/(?!search)(.+) https://$server_name/base/search/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of `[^\d]+`? Did you try testing from a new browser?

Comment: I'm trying to use the `[^\d]+$` so that it doesn't match URIs that end in numeric digits. And... wow you're right. My browser was using the cached redirect from earlier attempts. This works!! Thank you. 

Comment: Minor improvement: `rewrite ^/base/(?!search/)(.+)` otherwise your regex won't work for `/base/searching/abc`

Comment: Thank you, that's a good point.